# Javascript test with radio buttons and array

Tags: javascript, html, validation, radio-button

I'm learning Javascript and I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about creating a test with pure Javascript (no jQuery).

Ideal situation:

1. User is presented with a question and given the option of radio buttons.
2. User selects radio buttons depending on the question
3. On submit the choices are compared with an array containing answers.
4. Radio buttons cannot be left blank. If a choice does not equal the answer then alert the user.

So far I have tried nested `for` loops and separated `if/else` statements to no avail.

Big thanks in advance!

```js
var answers = [
 0, // Answer for question0
  1, // Answer for question1
  2 // Answer for question2
];

var question = [];

function grade(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    question[i] = document.querySelector("input[name='question" +  i + "']");
    if(question[i].checked){
      if(question[i].value = answers[i]){
        alert("question " + i + " is correct!");
      }
      else{
        alert("Incorrect! Try again.");
      }
    } 
    else{
      alert("Select a valid choice!");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="question0" value="0">Option A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question0" value="1">Option B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question0" value="2">Option C
  
  <hr>
  
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="0">Option A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="0">Option B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="0">Option C
  
  <hr>
  
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="0">Option A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">Option B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">Option C<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">Option D
  
  <hr>
  
  <input type="submit" onClick="grade();" value="Grade">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below code i hope it will help of you.

> I have add one hidden field for get total questions.

**HTML**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="question_form">
    <input type="radio" name="question0" value="0">Option A<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question0" value="1">Option B<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question0" value="2">Option C

    <hr>

    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="0">Option A<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">Option B<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="0">Option C

    <hr>

    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="0">Option A<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">Option B<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">Option C<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">Option D

    <hr>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_total_questions" value="3" />
    <input type="submit" onClick="return grade();" value="Grade">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function grade(){
        var answers = [
            0, // Answer for question0
            1, // Answer for question1
            2 // Answer for question2
        ];
        var flag_ = [];

        var hidden_total_questions = document.getElementById('hidden_total_questions');

        for(i=0;i<hidden_total_questions.value;i++){
            var questions_ = document.getElementsByName('question'+i);
            for(que in questions_){
                if(questions_[que].checked == true){
                    if(answers[i]==questions_[que].value){
                        flag_[i]=1;
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        flag_[i]=2;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    flag_[i]=0;
                }
            }
            if(flag_[i]==0){
                alert("Please select answer for "+i+" question.");
            }
            else if(flag_[i]==2){
                alert("Incorrect answer for "+i+" question.");
            }
            if(flag_[i]==1){
                alert("Correct answer for "+i+" question.");
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @downvoter please explain any doubt / issue / query so i can resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Please find edited working code. it may help you.

```js
var answers = [
    0, // Answer for question0
  1, // Answer for question1
  2 // Answer for question2
];

var question = [];

function grade(){

  for (var i = 0, ques = 3; i < ques; i++) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('question'+ i +'[]');

    for (var j = 0, length = radios.length; j < length; j++) {
        if (radios[j].checked) {

            if(radios[j].value == answers[i]){
              alert("question " + i + " is correct!");
            }
            else{
              alert("Incorrect! Try again.");
            }

            break;
        }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="question0[]" value="0">Option A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question0[]" value="1">Option B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question0[]" value="2">Option C

  <hr>

  <input type="radio" name="question1[]" value="0">Option A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question1[]" value="1">Option B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question1[]" value="2">Option C

  <hr>

  <input type="radio" name="question2[]" value="0">Option A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question2[]" value="1">Option B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question2[]" value="2">Option C<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question2[]" value="3">Option D

  <hr>

  <input type="button" onClick="grade();" value="Grade">
</form>
```